# Back Stack And Intent Flag Not working

Tags: android, android-intent, launchmode

IN my app launcher is activity A, then user go to Activity B then Activity C then Activity D. From D if user perform some action then user should redirect to activity E.

Like A->B->C->D->E

Now if user press back button from activity E then he should move to Activity A. How can i set intent flag to achive this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html and this https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: `finish();` other activity  so if you back than direct to activity A .

Comment: From B->E just call finish when ever you are switching intent.. then upon pressing back on E only A will be in stack

Comment: But in that case if some one press back from D then also redirect to A instead ob C.

Comment: I just want to do it using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK like flag.

Comment: @RaviBhandari check my below ans

Answer (score 2):

you can try..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(E.this, A.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: `NEW_TASK` is not necessary here. `CLEAR_TOP` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This will just start another instance of `A` on top of the existing instance of `E`. Probably not what OP wants.